# Tic Tac Toe not changing colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im making a basic tic tac toe game using Jquery and CSS. I want to make it so that clicking the div adds player one's color and dblclicking adds player two's color. For some reason the color isn't changing for playerOne.

HMTL

```
<body>
 <table>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
  <tr></tr>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
    <td><div class="dot"></div></td>
 </table>
```

CSS

```
table{
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
  border-spacing:7px;
}
.dot{
  border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#A8A8A8;
}
.playerOne{
  border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
  border-radius:50px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('playerOne');
  });
});
```

Comment: Work for me http://jsfiddle.net/Yw66x/

Comment: Why doesn't it work for me. Im using CodePen

Comment: Figured it out. Jquery was not enabled under JavaScript. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to reference JQuery? Add this to your HTML page above the code.

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You may wish to use a more recent version of jQuery though, 1.7.1 is pretty old ;)

Answer (score 0):

you could color the event.target parameter as well

see http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/GbyAY/

```
$(function() {
    $('div').on('click', function(e) {
        $(e.target).addClass('playerOne');
    });
});
```